# Angular - convert a function into a promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

Consider the following pseudo code:

```
// main
function1();
function2();

...
//the rest of the code
....

// function1:
someservice.getPhone().then(calback1);
// function2:
someservice.getAddress().then(calback2);
```

What can I do to ensure that the rest of the code is not executed until both function1 and function2 get thru their callbacks?

Thanks

Comment: If u want to wait for several promises - use $q.all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.then` method of a promise always returns a derived promise. Use those derived promises to delay execution of subsequent functions.

```
// function1:
var derivedPromise1 = service.getPhone().then(calback1);
// function2:
var derivedPromise2 = someservice.getAddress().then(calback2);

$q.all([derivedPromise1, derivedPromise2])
  .then(function onFulfilled(resultArray) {
       //code placed here
}).catch(function onRejected(errorResult) {
      //error handling code here
});
```

The `$q` service will wait for successful completion of  `callback1` and `callback2` before invoking the code in the `onFulfilled` function. Otherwise the `$q` service will invoke the `onRejected` function for the first rejected promise.

Comment: Love the idea, but my testing is not working in that way. I am getting to "//code placed here" before calback2 finishes. Plus, I am not calling service functions directly. They are called in function1 and finction2. A, I see. Finction1 and function2 have to return these service calls.

Comment: When functions are *nested* in other functions (or service calls), there should be  `return` statements at every level of the hierarchy.